# Can the compiled opencl program be stored as a seperate binary file?

Tags: python, opencl, gpgpu, pyopencl, amd-processor

I have 2 two python script on separate files. The first one has opencl program that performs some image processing on the image passed to it and returns the results. The second script reads the image on from a file and calls the first script passing the read image as a parameter and obtains the results returned by it which is used for further processing.

Now, I have like a 100 images in the folder. So the second scripts calls the first script 100 times and each time the first script is called, the opencl kernel is compiled which is absolutely unnecessary as all the images are of same format and dimension.  Is there a way to first compile the opencl kernel once, store it in a binary format and call it whenever required? Of-course, i can put all the code in one large file, compile the kernel once and call it in a loop for 100 times but I want separate files for the purpose of convenience.

Hardware:

CPU: AMD A8 APU, AMD Phenom 2 X4

GPU: AMD Radeon HD 7640G + 7670M Dual Graphics, ATI Radeon HD5770

Comment: Do you really think having two scripts, one of which compiles and caches an OpenCL program, is more convenient than simply refactoring both scripts into one? Python has module support to do this cleanly.

Comment: Well indeed you are right, it is convenient to combine the 2 scripts into 1, but these two scripts are part of a collection of 10s of scripts. I am aware of python's module support and I am using it. I just wanted to know if it is possible to compile and store the opencl kernel as binary file and load it when ever required, rather than compiling it at run-time, every time it is required......

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get the compiled "binary" of a program via `clGetProgramInfo()` and store it. You would then load the program with `clCreateProgramWithBinary()` instead of `clCreateProgramWithSource()`.

But then you are using PyOpenCL which [automatically caches](http://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/runtime.html#pyopencl.Program.build) program binaries.

Comment: Exactly. Also, NVIDIA caches binaries automatically. Your first compile takes longer than all subsequent ones.

Answer (score 1):

on NVIDIA the binary will be in the ptx format.
obtain the Binary sizes 
clGetProgramInfo() using the flag CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES

store the binaries in ptx file.
clGetProgramInfo() using the flag CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES

clCreateProgramWithBinary() with the ptx file as input.

Comment: There is still compilation occurring if you do that. PTX is only an intermediate representation of the final code that runs on the hardware, and the driver needs to compile it before it can be used.

Comment: @ user1822771 Sorry for not providing info on the hardware. I have updated my post. I am using AMD hardware, will it be the same?